# WinPE, Startnet.CMD and passing variables to second batch file not working

Tags: windows, batch, winpe

I don't know scripting or PowerShell (yes I need to learn something). I'm not an expert batch file maker either.

I have a WinPE flash drive which I used to deploy OS images.  I have the WIM, drivers and anything needed else outside the WinPE environment to ensure that
Updates, changes are easier for me to make.

I use the "STARTNET.CMD" batch file which is part of the WinPE.

The reason to go through the letter drives is that the WinPE always gets the X letter drive assigned. The flash drive itself can receive a random letter which always changes.

My deployment menu is located on the flash drive it self and not inside the WinPE. This is so that if I need to make a change I don't have to re-do the WinPE.

I am able to locate the "menu.bat" batch file and launch it.
I use a variable to capture the letter drive.
I call the second batch file named "menu.bat" and pass the variable to it.

When the second batch file loads, I believe that I am calling the variable correctly.  If I break out of the batch file I can echo the variable and see the expected reply.
The issue is that I can't use the variable to work with anything on the second batch file.
In my test, I can get this to work over and over.
When it runs from the real USB flash drive it does not work.
I removed comments from the second batch file to make it smaller.

My issue is that files below all get a message stating that the system cannot find the path specified.

```
Diskpart
Imagex.exe
bcdboot.exe
```

Why can't I get the varible to properly function when I try to using example "ImageX.exe"?

#### Contents of the Startnet.cmd

```
@echo off
for %%p in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do if exist %%p:\Tools\ set w=%%p
Set execpatch=%w%\Tools\
call %w%:\Menu.bat \Tools\
```

#### Contents of the Menu.BAT

```
@echo off
set SecondPath=%1
cls
:Start
cls
Echo.
Echo.==============================================================
Echo. Windows 7 64 Bit Ent Basic Desktops
Echo.==============================================================
Echo.
Echo A. 790 Windows 7 - Basic
Echo.
Echo.
Echo I. Exit
Echo.
Echo.

set /p choice=Choose your option = 

if not '%choice%'=='' set choice=%choice:~0,1%

if '%choice%'=='a' goto 790_Windows_7_Basic

echo "%choice%" is not a valid (answer/command)
echo.

goto start
:790_Windows_7_Basic

REM DISKPART /s %SecondPath%BatchFiles\Make-Partition.txt

%SecondPath%imagex.exe /apply %SecondPath%Images\Win7-64b-Ent-Basic-SysPreped.wim 1 o:\ /verify

%SecondPath%bcdboot.exe o:\Windows /s S:

Copy %SecondPath%Unattended\unattend.XML o:\Windows\System32\sysprep\unattend.XML /y

xcopy %SecondPath%Drivers\790\*.* o:\Windows\INF\790\ /E /Q /Y

MD o:\Windows\Setup\Scripts\
Copy %SecondPath%BatchFiles\SetupComplete.cmd o:\Windows\Setup\Scripts\ /y

Goto Done

:Done
Exit
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please take care to format your posts correctly. Insert code, select it and press `Ctrl-K` to indent it so it is shown as code. For the future, check our formatting help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it, the last line in your `startnet.cmd` file should be

```
call %w%:\Menu.bat %w%:\Tools\
```

since `menu.bat` is apparently expecting the first argument to be the complete path to the Tools directory, including the drive letter.

Note that `startnet.cmd` sets an environment variable named `w` which `menu.bat` could use (but currently doesn't!) so another solution would be to replace all the instances of `%SecondPath%` with `%w%:%SecondPath%`.

Comment: What did end up working was to use:

Comment: What did work was to end up using the first variable that I set.  The first variable is called %MainPath% and was recommended by a co-worker to pass that variable to the second batch file but sue a different name for the vairable to prevent confusion.  Well, that did not work but what did work was to se:                           %MainPatch%\Images\*.wim etc.  I will test as you suggestion though for my own knowledge.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does using Setx help?  It modifies the user or system environment environment.  Look at `Setx /?` for more

Comment: Never heard of that command but it should pretty good.  I will test with it - thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should check "\sources\boot.wim" file, open this file, and then check these "\tools\imagex.exe and bcdboot.exe" files have correct directory in boot.wim.

Comment: yes everything is in the correct directory and if I run all manually it works.  Is the batch file that does not.  Harry Johnson's response actually helped solve my issue